# Why do I get the "Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor" error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to fit a neural network with training data, but keep getting errors like this when reaching the fit function:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I don't understand why I get this error when fitting. Because as you can see [from the official Keras documentation here](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/fit.html), the fit function accepts lists and arrays. I have tried to pass both but always get errors.

Passing lists:

```
... gathering all trainig data ...

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(DICTIONNARY_SIZE, 120, input_length = NR_OF_TRAINING_VECTORS))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model.add(LSTM(176, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

print("type: " , type(trainingInput))
print("type[0]: " , type(trainingInput[0]))
print("type[0][0]: " , type(trainingInput[0][0]))

print("\n ")
print("type labels: " , type(trainingLabels))
print("type labels[0]: " , type(trainingLabels[0]))
print("type labels[0][0]: " , type(trainingLabels[0][0]))


model.fit(trainingInput, trainingLabels, epochs = 5, batch_size=NR_OF_TRAINIG_VECTORS, verbose = 'auto')
```

prints:

```
type:  <class 'list'>
type[0]:  <class 'list'>
type[0][0]:  <class 'int'>

 
type labels:  <class 'list'>
type labels[0]:  <class 'list'>
type labels[0][0]:  <class 'int'>
...
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I have tried converting the data like this as well:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(DICTIONNARY_SIZE, 120, input_length = NR_OF_TRAINING_VECTORS))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model.add(LSTM(176, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

trainingInput = tf.constant(trainingInput, dtype=tf.float32)
trainingLabels = tf.constant(trainingLabels, dtype=tf.float32)    

print("type: " , type(trainingInput))
print("type[0]: " , type(trainingInput[0]))
print("type[0][0]: " , type(trainingInput[0][0]))

print("\n ")

print("type labels: " , type(trainingLabels))
print("type labels[0]: " , type(trainingLabels[0]))
print("type labels[0][0]: " , type(trainingLabels[0][0]))

model.fit(trainingInput, trainingLabels, epochs = 5, batch_size=NR_OF_TRAINIG_VECTORS, verbose = 'auto')
```

But this leads to the following error:

```
ValueError: Can't convert non-rectangular Python sequence to Tensor.
```

Lastly I have tried giving all my input training vectors the same length. Because the vectors are a series of integers and have varying lengths:

```
for i in range (NR_OF_TRAINIG_VECTORS):
    trainingInput[i] = trainingInput[i][:10]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(DICTIONNARY_SIZE, 120, input_length = NR_OF_TRAINING_VECTORS))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.4))
model.add(LSTM(176, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])

print("type: " , type(trainingInput))
print("type[0]: " , type(trainingInput[0]))
print("type[0][0]: " , type(trainingInput[0][0]))

print("\n ")

print("type labels: " , type(trainingLabels))
print("type labels[0]: " , type(trainingLabels[0]))
print("type labels[0][0]: " , type(trainingLabels[0][0]))

model.fit(trainingInput, trainingLabels, epochs = 5, batch_size=NR_OF_TRAINIG_VECTORS, verbose = 'auto')
```

But this again leads to issues:

```
type:  <class 'list'>
type[0]:  <class 'list'>
type[0][0]:  <class 'int'>

type labels:  <class 'list'>
type labels[0]:  <class 'list'>
type labels[0][0]:  <class 'int'>

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

At this point I am not quite sure anymore of how I have to structure my vectors in order to not have issues any more.

What do I have to do at this point?

Comment: Have you tried to convert by using `numpy.array(trainingInput)`?

Comment: @I'mnotarobot, yes. This lead to the following error when calling the fit function:  Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)
Any other suggestion?